# how do I get vector ("x", "z") from string "y ~ x + z"?

Tags: r

I have a regression formula string `"y ~ x + z"`. How do I get `"x"` and `"z"` from it? I need to get the column names I use for regression..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert the string to `formula` object and get the variables with `all.vars`.  The first element would be the dependent variable, so it is removed with indexing (`[-1]`)

```
all.vars(as.formula(str1))[-1]
#[1] "x" "z"
```

---

Or as @ducymayr mentioned

```
attr(terms(as.formula(str1)), "term.labels")
#[1] "x" "z"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "y ~ x + z"
```

Comment: Using the `labels` method for a `terms` object would be better - `labels(terms(as.formula(str1)))` - from `?terms` - *There are ‘print’ and ‘labels’ methods for class ‘"terms"’: the latter prints the term labels (see ‘terms.object’).*